# How to find the inverse of this matrix? (in order to solve the question).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am trying to solve this question and things got really complicated while trying to find the inverse of the matrix, here's the question: 
Given $
A = \left[\begin{array}{l}a&1&-1\\1&a&-1\\1&-1&a\end{array}\right]$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$, if $A$ is invertible, then $(A)_{11}*(A^{-1})_{11}=?$ 
I started to doubt myself since I reached $\left[\begin{array}{l}a&1&-1\\0&a-\frac{1}{a}&-1+\frac{1}{a}\\0&-1-\frac{1}{a}&a+\frac{1}{a}\end{array}\right]$. 
And I couldn't figure out how to keep going, and started to doubt I'm missing something (or I'm just weak at finding inverse matrix). 
Note I checked the determinant and got that it's invertible if and only if $a \ne 0,1,2$ so there's not problem with dividing by $a$. 

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $(A)_{11}=a$ is obvious.  $(A^{-1})_{11}$ is clearly $(a^2+1)/\det A$ by cofactors, so it remains to evaluate $\det A$.

Comment: @user10354138 thank you for the help, could you elaborate a little on $(A^{-1})_{11}$? I can't understand how you can find it yet using the determinant.

Comment: It amounts to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3_%C3%97_3_matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asked only to find the product $(A)_{11} \cdot \left( A^{-1} \right)_{11}$, you only need to find the $(1,1)$-entry of $A^{-1}$ and not the whole matrix. For this purpose, since the matrix is $3 \times 3$ it is useful to use the formula for the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). We have

$$ \det(A) = a \cdot (a^2 - 1) - (a - 1) + (-1 + a) = a \cdot (a^2 - 1), \\
\operatorname{adj}(A)_{11} = a^2 - 1 $$
and hence
$$ \left( A^{-1} \right)_{11} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \left( \operatorname{adj}(A) \right)_{11} = \frac{a^2 - 1}{a \cdot (a^2 - 1)} = \frac{1}{a}.$$

---

Alternatively, let's write

$$ A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} x & ? & ? \\ y & ? & ? \\ z & ? & ? \end{pmatrix}. $$

We need to find $x$. Since $A \cdot A^{-1} = I$, we must have
$$ ax + y - z = 1, \\
 x + ay - z = 0,\\
 x - y + az = 0. $$

There are three equations for three unknowns (where $a$ is a parameter) and the augmented matrix associated to this system is
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & a & -1 & 0 \\ 
1 & -1 & a & 0 \end{array} \right). $$

Performing elementary operations, we get the equivalent system
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & a & -1 & 0 \\ 
1 & -1 & a & 0 \end{array} \right) \xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & -1 & 0 \\
a & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 
1 & -1 & a & 0 \end{array}  \right) \xrightarrow{R_2 = R_2 - aR_1, R_3 = R_3 
- R_1}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 - a^2 & a - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & -1 - a & a + 1 & 0 \end{array}  \right)
\xrightarrow{ R_2 = R_2 + (1 - a) R_3}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a(1-a) & 1 \\ 
0 & -1 - a & a + 1 & 0 \end{array}  \right) 
$$
which translates into the system
$$
x + ay - z = 0, \\
a(1-a)z = 1, \\
(a+1)z = (a+1)y.
$$

Hence, $z = y  = \frac{1}{a(1-a)}$  and $x = z - ay = \frac{1}{a(1-a)} - \frac{1}{1-a} = \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, seems like I'm solving some unrelevant question since I didn't learn about the adjugate matrix, do you think there's anyway to find $(A^{-1})_{11}$ without using the formula for the adjugate matrix?

Comment: @Pwaol: There are many ways to solve this question. You can perform Gaussian elimination or even work up directly with the definition. I'll add another solution in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks alot! I appreciate the help.